# weird issue with graphics or browser?

Tags: windows, windows-8, browser, desktop-computer, opera

I have an annoying issue I get this visual problem:

[image: http://imgur.com/Pdq05mL]

My browser is Opera.

I have tried changing refresh rate from 60 to 75 Hz but sometimes it doesn't improve.

System props: [system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qCih.png) + NVIDIA GeForce 7900 GS

But with Desktop not always the graphics gone crazy

Edit: the issue went away temporary I did nothing

Comment: Does this only happen with opera or other browsers as well?  What are the specs of your system?

Comment: with Google Chrome too

Comment: Have you tried updating your graphics drivers?

Comment: No I'll try do this

Comment: It looks like someone took the definition of AngularJS a bit too seriously :)

Comment: "No certified downloads were found for this configuration. To include beta downloads in your search, click here." for GeForce 7 Series GeForce 7900 GS, win 8.1 32-bit